# Requiere de HTTPS Keycloak20.0.0

Tags: linux, keycloak

actualmente necesito poder instalar un servidor con el servicio de Keycloak para porbar el SSO pero al momento de subirlo en un docker se me esta presentando muchos problemas.

Version a instalar Keycloak 20.0.0

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Este es el comando docker que ejecute

```
docker run \
  --name keycloak \
  -e KEYCLOAK_ADMIN=admin \
  -e KEYCLOAK_ADMIN_PASSWORD=admin \
  -e KC_HTTPS_CERTIFICATE_FILE=/root/server.crt.pem \
  -e KC_HTTPS_CERTIFICATE_KEY_FILE=/root/server.key.pem \
  -v $PWD/server.crt.pem:/root/server.crt.pem \
  -v $PWD/server.key.pem:/root/server.key.pem  \
  -p 9090:9090 \
  -p 8080:8080 \
  -p 443:443 \
  quay.io/keycloak/keycloak:20.0.1 \
  start-dev
```

Segui los comandos que indican que se puede deshabilitar el ssl como lo indican en esta publicacion: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49859066/keycloak-docker-https-required y aun asi tampoco he podido. da error

```
bash-4.4$ ./kcadm.sh config credentials --server http://110.238.66.22:8080/auth --realm master --user admin --password admin
Logging into http://110.238.66.22:8080/auth as user admin of realm master
null [RESTEASY003210: Could not find resource for full path: http://110.238.66.22:8080/auth/realms/master/protocol/openid-connect/token]
bash-4.4$ ./kcadm.sh update realms/master -s sslRequired=NONE
No server specified. Use --server, or 'kcadm.sh config credentials or connection'.
bash-4.4$ ./kcadm.sh update --server http://110.238.66.22:8080/auth realms/master -s sslRequired=NONE
No realm or token specified. Use --realm, --token, or 'kcadm.sh config credentials'.
```

Ya no se que mas hacer. Este keycloak no corre en localhost, esta siendo expuesto por una IP publica, pero asi no me permite. ya intente configurarlo con la guia de Keycloak original https://www.keycloak.org/getting-started/getting-started-docker y tampoco si le quiero pasar los parametros de certificado :https://www.keycloak.org/server/enabletls tampoco me lo permite.

Answer (score 0):

Debe de tener algo así parecido yo lo expuse para EC2 de AWS:

Mi docker-comose:

```
keycloak_server:
container_name: id-keycloakServer
image: quay.io/keycloak/keycloak:latest
restart: always
command:
 - start-dev
depends_on:
 - postgres_db
environment:
  KEYCLOAK_ADMIN: admin
  KEYCLOAK_ADMIN_PASSWORD: tupassword
  KC_DB: postgres
  KC_DB_URL: jdbc:postgresql://postgres_db/keycloak
  KC_DB_PASSWORD: tupassword
  KC_DB_USERNAME: postgres
  KC_HTTPS_CERTIFICATE_FILE: /opt/keycloak/conf/server.crt.pem
  KC_HTTPS_CERTIFICATE_KEY_FILE: /opt/keycloak/conf/server.key.pem
volumes:
  - /home/rizzoli/docker-compose/server.crt.pem:/opt/keycloak/conf/server.crt.pem
  - /home/rizzoli/docker-compose/server.key.pem:/opt/keycloak/conf/server.key.pem
ports:
  - 8443:8443
```

Recuerda crear el certificado para mi caso lo realice con openssl.

Cuando valides a tu URL: seria https://tuipservidor:8443